# Answer starting at -1 score

Tags: support, answers, reputation

Ok, so I just searched Meta and the Help Center for an explanation of what I just saw, but found none.

The matter is that I was answering a simple question about threading, and when I posted my answer, it was *already* at `-1`. I'm not saying that it was at `0` and then it quickly changed to `-1`; no, it showed a score of `-1` right as I clicked "Post your answer" (even the orange background was still fading out...).

How is that possible? Is there some kind of reason to make answers start at negative scores? Some kind of answer semi-ban that still accepts answers but posts them with lower scores?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, your answer still starts at 0. Somebody who was on the question's page already, got the '1 new answer' message, clicked on it, <s>read your answer carefully</s> and decided to downvote it. This all happened before your submit reloaded the page (maybe your Internet connection is a bit slow), therefore it *appeared* to have started at -1, but it didn't. You can check the [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/40906592/timeline) to see it has a real downvote, but it's not clear exactly at what moment that happened.

Comment: Yup, that's a possibility. It's just that everything was so... instantaneous, that I honestly find it hard to believe it (I've got a 100 Mbps line and `ping stackoverflow.com` gives just 55ms), but I guess it could happen. Thanks for the "timeline" link, btw! I didn't know that existed :-) (PS: will probably accept your answer later, don't want to kill the thread so soon).

Comment: Just note that all answers except one have a down vote, including the deleted answer.

Comment: It could be a SCITE, yes.

Comment: @walen You can check the timestamps to the second from your profile page/activity, hover over the timestamp to see it (`hh:mm` format in the "Reputation" section, `n D(ays)` in the "All actions" section)

Comment: @Glorfindel Nice username (just noticed, sorry)! I didn't know what SCITE was [until now](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18014/what-is-fgitw-and-scite), TIL. Thank you and thanks rene for noticing.

Comment: @chrki yeah, I know about that, but is there a way to check the timestamp for a downvote?

Comment: @walen You should be able to see individual rep changes + timestamps when expanding the secions under `All activity -> Reputation` (on the desktop page that is, not sure about mobile view/app)

Comment: @chrki You're right :D I couldn't see it because I was checking my profile from Meta, and the `reputation` tab wasn't showing. I checked from SO and it's right there. FYI the timestamps are 09:14:48 for the answer and 09:14:53 for the downvote :/

Comment: Minor note (cc @walen): there *are* such bad (read: of blatantly low quality) questions that almost all answers to it will "not be helpful", and thus deserve a downvote. It often happens in tags I follow. Then again, I read and assess each answer before downvoting them.

Comment: Wait, we're basing voting on objective criteria now? I must have missed that memo.